# Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil' in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting following error in production but the same is not a repro in in local.

> Error executing child request for
>   handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.
>   Inner Exception: Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown.

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__11()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)   
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)\n Inner Exception:
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
```

Can anybody tell me what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced the above issue and the exception was logged because of calling handler twice
for example In our case we are calling Response.Redirect handler twice. i.e. we set it to go to Home page and then again call to redirect to FAQ page then the above exception will be thrown
for that keep a check

```
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected){}
```

Comment: How do you put this code in the controller? You still have to return a View? I have the same problem but not quite sure if it can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: The exception will be logged even before view is returned