# MVC3 wont work after deploy

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment

I currently develop an MVC3 Application(Win XP IIS 5.4) and it works fine for me on my local host with the IIS.

Now I published and deployed the app on a Win XP embedded PC on IIS 5.4 and i get this error :

```
 Error executing child request for handler   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
```

full trace:

```
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)    
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)     
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)     
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)    
at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\publish\Views\Home\Index.vbhtml:line 45    
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()     
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()     
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()     
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)     
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)     
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

on line 45 in my Home/index.vbhtml i render other actions like this:

```
@Code
   Html.RenderAction("MobileCollection", "Setting")
   Html.RenderAction("MobileCollection", "Teaching")
   'Html.RenderAction("MobileCollection", "IO")
   Html.RenderAction("MobileCollection", "Home")
End Code
```

I have no clue why this is not working on the other system...

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708942/error-executing-child-request-for-handler-system-web-mvc-httphandlerutil-in-as

Comment: maybe asp mvc 3 is not installed on remote server?you could also try to turn on view compiling on your local machine and check if everything is ok

Comment: @0lukasz0 This could be the solution, i installed MVC3 by "ASP MVC3 Update tools setup.exe" because the webinstaller wont work on my testmachine..

Comment: refering to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768070/how-best-to-install-mvc-3-on-a-server i dont need to install mvc3 on the server... still got this error